# Reproduce article's default table of contents with the "titletoc" package

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I'm currently trying to create my own class and in it I change the colors on the sectioning commands, in order to do that I used the "titlesec" package to change from `\section` to `\subsubsection` and redifine `\part` myself. The problem that I have is that the simply addition of the "titlesec" package messes with the ToC.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Error with titlesec}
\author{AmadoC}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

this document \textbf{does not} include the \texttt{titlesec} package

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\part{Lorem}
\part{ipsum}
\section{dolor}
\section{sit}
\section{amet}
\subsection{consectetur}
\subsection{adipiscing}
\subsection{elit}

\end{document}
```

just add the package to the code to see the difference.

So in order to correct that error and create a new list of problems for my class, I was thinking to use the "titletoc" package, but I can't reproduce the article's default ToC. Does anyone know how to do that or another way around my problem?